# SELECT Statement for cocktail db

Tags: sql

This is probably pretty simple and dumb to ask but Im just not getting there right now. I have a db for cocktails and want to check which cocktails I can make with the available ingredients:

> Get the names of all cocktails where **every** ingredient is in stock

These are my tables:

```
create table cocktails
(
  name TEXT PRIMARY KEY
)

create table ingredients
(
  name TEXT PRIMARY KEY
)

create table cocktail_ingredients
(
  cocktail_name   TEXT    ,
  ingredient_name TEXT    ,
  amount          INTEGER ,

  FOREIGN KEY ( cocktail_name   ) REFERENCES cocktails(   name ) ,
  FOREIGN KEY ( ingredient_name ) REFERENCES ingredients( name )

)

create table ingredients_in_stock
(
  ingredient_name TEXT ,

  FOREIGN KEY ( ingredient_name ) REFERENCES ingredients ( name )
)
```

And this is my code so far:

```
SELECT ci.cocktail_name
FROM cocktail_ingredients ci
WHERE ci.ingredient_name IN ( SELECT iis.ingredient_name
                              FROM ingredients_in_stock iis
                            )
GROUP BY ci.cocktail_name
HAVING COUNT(*) = ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM ingredients_in_stock
                  )
;
```

Comment: I can only get "all cocktails that use every ingredient in stock" and not "all cocktails where every ingredient is in stock".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correlated subquery should work:

```
select cocktail_name as all_ingredients_in_stock 
from cocktail_ingredients ci
inner join ingredients_in_stock iis 
    on ci.ingredient_name = iis.ingredient_name
group by cocktail_name
having count(*) = 
    (select count(*) 
    from cocktail_ingredients 
    where cocktail_name = ci.cocktail_name
)
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b895f/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a LEFT JOIN and a IN clause for this. Something like this:

```
SELECT name FROM cocktails WHERE Name NOT IN(
SELECT DISTINCT ci.cocktail_name FROM cocktail_ingredients ci LEFT JOIN ingredients_in_stock istk
ON ci.ingredient_name=istk.ingredient_name WHERE istk.ingredient_name IS NULL)
```

This query inverts the logic: List the cocktails where none of it's ingredients are missing on the ingredients_in_stock table. Hope the idea helps you

Comment: Looks like a really nice query. Cannot test-run it, but it seems to really nail it with minimal bloat.

Comment: +1 for more compact than my attempt. And more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You could just say something like this:

```
select ci.name
from      cocktail_ingredients ci
left join ingredients_in_stock iis on iis.ingredient_name = ci.ingredient_name
group by ci.name
having count(ci.ingredient_name) = sum( case
                                        when iis.ingredient_name is not null
                                        then 1
                                        else 0
                                        end
                                      )
```

In the `having` clause,

- The `count(ci.ingredient_name)` gives you the total number of ingredients required for the cocktail
- The `sum()` expression gives you the count of in-stock ingredients used by the cocktail.

Comment: @PawelP - Nope. The raw result set is partitioned into groups based on the `group by` clause. Aggregate expressions are then evaluated for each group and the group is collapsed into a single row. The `having` clause is then applied to filter the aggregated groups.